# mysqli query select * not returning a certain field

Tags: php, mysql

only 1 field is not returned, the rest of it is returned correctly

the problem is I used the same query for other page and it returned everything okay

the problematic PHP :

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM produk INNER JOIN kategori ON produk.id_kategori=kategori.id_kategori WHERE id_produk='$_GET[id]'");
$r=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

echo"judul produk : $r[nama_produk] <br />
      nama kategori : $r[nama_kategori]<br />
      judul gambar : $r[gambar]";
```

the results :

judul produk : test mesin kyocera

nama kategori : kyocera

judul gambar :

another php, used on other page which is pretty much the same but works fine :

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM produk INNER JOIN kategori2 ON produk.id_kategori2=kategori2.id_kategori2 ORDER BY rand() DESC LIMIT 25");
while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
include "diskon_stok.php";
    echo"
    <div class='container_produk'>
      <div class='preview'>
            <span style='font-size : 22px'>$r[nama_kategori2]</span>
            <span style='font-size : 14px'>$r[preview]</span>
            <button class='pre-button'><a href='produk-$r[id_produk]-$r[nama_produk].html'>Detail</a></button>
      </div>
        <img style='margin-left : 5%;' src='foto_produk/small_$r[gambar]'/>
        <div class='detail'> 
            <span style='font-size : 22px'>$r[nama_produk]</span>
            $divharga
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>

    </div>
";
}
```

now the field not returned is $r[gambar] on Code 1, but on Code 2 $r[gambar] is returned and thus the image is showing on browser

so did I do something wrong somewhere?

Comment: you are joining a different table in your second query. you should run both querys in phpmyadmin or a mysql console and check if you actually get data for both - maybe in your first query, gambar is just NULL? also: $r[gambar] is bad style and should throw you warnings, and including a _GET-parameter directly in your query string is a huge risk for SQL-injections.

Comment: you used two different tables see this in 1st query `INNER JOIN kategori` but 2nd table `INNER JOIN kategori2`. also echo your query and run in console and chec the output. the number `2` is included

Comment: the second query is fine, everything in second query is returned correctly

the problem is in the first query which is simpler than the second but 1 field is not returned, the rest of the field is returned

Comment: yes of course I used different table because that is my purpose, there are 2 tables : kategori and kategori2

Comment: okay . .  R u echo your query?? run in console

Comment: this is the screenshot of result for 2nd query http://imgur.com/a/XI9kp  

as you can see, it works fine, the image and everything is returned

Comment: try to run your query first on phpmyadmin and see the result,.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: We don't really need to see the PHP code. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out my query is wrong

it should be written like this

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM produk,kategori WHERE produk.id_kategori=kategori.id_kategori AND id_produk='$_GET[id]'");
$r=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
```

no need to type INNER JOIN or JOIN